# How distinguish stage of infra vs stage of software in naming convention (IaC)

Tags: azure, terraform, naming-conventions, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

For our Microsoft Azure resources we have a naming convention as follows:

`{productName}-{stage}-{azureRegion}-{type}-{resourceType}[-{NN}]`

Where:

- *stage* indicates the 'enviroment' or 'stage' of the software running on the infra, "dev", "test" or "prod"
- *type* is used to group resources into, "data" (e.g. databases), "app" or "shared" (e.g. networking).

We want all stages of the software to run on production grade infra. But now, when experimenting with new infra, the naming convention leaves no room for these experiments. This is a problem because some resource names need to be globally unigue resulting in clashes.

**Question**

How do others distinguish between the *stage of the software* and the *stage of the infra* in the naming convention?

Comment: when experimenting, you could define whatever name ? saying if only POC it s not prod ready so you dont really care ?

Comment: saying that you could always use `stage=poc` or whatever for experimentation

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I think that could work. Although *stage* not only reflects the software stage then. But I should probably look at it as the *environment*